# java label exporting a blank image

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, bufferedimage, drawimage

My java code places a image on a label which in the code is label1. When the user hits button b1 it should export the image in a specific size. Right now a image file is exported but it is just a black screen. The image on the label is not being transferred. I want the image on the label to be transferred.

```
   JLabel labels = new JLabel("Label 2");  
        static JButton b1 = new JButton("First");

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



  BufferedImage scaledButtonImage =
      new BufferedImage(400, 1000, bimg.getType());
          Graphics g1 = scaledButtonImage.createGraphics();
      g1.drawImage(scaledButtonImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);                  
      g1.dispose();


              label2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bimg));

          try {


              ImageIO.write(scaledButtonImage, "png",file);

          } 

            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Right now a image file is exported but it is just a black screen.

```
g1.drawImage(scaledButtonImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
```

Read the API for the `drawImage(…)` method.

You are not specifying the width/height parameters of the image you want to draw, so nothing is begin drawn.

Also, you are drawing the BufferedImage onto itself.

If you want to draw the Image from the label you need code like:

```
ImageIcon icon = (ImageIcon)label.getIcon();
g1.drawImage(icon.getImage(), …);
```

Comment: what do i put in the ... part?

Comment: As I said in my first comment, read the API for the drawImage(….) method. Your question stated: **it should export the image in a specific size.** I don't know what size you want for your image so I can't tell you what the parameters should be. Keep a reference to the API handy so you can verify how each parameter is used.

Comment: @BenEdge, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved

Comment: your answer did not help me sorry.

Comment: How did it not help? Where is your code that implement the suggestions made? Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.